# Sql Union a number of tables together

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to get the total count from 4 different tables using the union but i'm not sure how to get this to work..

My code for the single table count which works fine,

```
SELECT (Select count(*) 
        FROM (SELECT RN, DP, DT, Min(ED) AS MinDate 
              FROM ECount1 
              GROUP BY RN, DP, DT) as x 
        WHERE DT = 'STR'  
          AND MONTH(MinDate) >= '07' 
          AND Month(MinDate) <= '09') as StrAFT
```

i thought i could just add a union but this doesn't work?
Something like this?

```
SELECT (Select count(*) FROM 
(SELECT RN, DP, DT, Min(ED) AS MinDate FROM ECount1 GROUP BY RN, DP, DT) as x WHERE DT = 'STR' AND MONTH(MinDate) >= '07' and Month(MinDate) <= '09'
UNION
SELECT RN, DP, DT, Min(ED) AS MinDate FROM ECount2 GROUP BY RN, DP, DT) as x WHERE DT = 'STR' AND MONTH(MinDate) >= '07' and Month(MinDate) <= '09'
UNION
SELECT RN, DP, DT, Min(ED) AS MinDate FROM ECount3 GROUP BY RN, DP, DT) as x WHERE DT = 'STR' AND MONTH(MinDate) >= '07' and Month(MinDate) <= '09'
UNION
SELECT RN, DP, DT, Min(ED) AS MinDate FROM ECount4 GROUP BY RN, DP, DT) as x WHERE DT = 'STR' AND MONTH(MinDate) >= '07' and Month(MinDate) <= '09'
) as StrAFT
```

Comment: "Doesn't work" isn't going to get you a lot of help.  How doesn't it work?  What are you expecting?

Comment: Your first line should just be `Select count(*) FROM`, not `SELECT (Select count(*) FROM`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested for Prissioner use `UNION ALL`

```
WITH cte as (
    SELECT * FROM ECount1 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT * FROM ECount2
    UNION ALL
    SELECT * FROM ECount3 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT * FROM ECount4
), calculate as (
    SELECT RN, DP, DT, Min(ED) AS MinDate 
    FROM cte 
    WHERE DT = 'STR'  
      AND MONTH(ED) >= '07' 
      AND MONTH(ED) <= '09
    GROUP BY RN, DP, DT
    HAVING MIN(ED) IS NOT NULL
)
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM calculate
```

For count for each month use `GROUP BY`

```
 SELECT MONTH(ED), COUNT(*)
 FROM calculate
 GROUP BY MONTH(ED)
```

OR use conditional count:

```
 SELECT COUNT(*), 
        COUNT (CASE WHEN MONTH(ED) = '07' THEN 1 END) as count_07,
        COUNT (CASE WHEN MONTH(ED) = '08' THEN 1 END) as count_08,
        COUNT (CASE WHEN MONTH(ED) = '09' THEN 1 END) as count_09
 FROM calculate
 GROUP BY MONTH(ED)
```

Comment: Say i wanted to return the count of each month in a seperate column could i move the Where month(ED) = '07' into the select count?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem you have is `UNION`, it will remove duplicate rows
You can use `UNION ALL` to keep those duplicate rows

```
Select count(*) FROM 
(
    SELECT RN, DP, DT, Min(ED) AS MinDate FROM ECount1 GROUP BY RN, DP, DT) as x WHERE DT = 'STR' AND MONTH(MinDate) >= '07' and Month(MinDate) <= '09'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT RN, DP, DT, Min(ED) AS MinDate FROM ECount2 GROUP BY RN, DP, DT) as x WHERE DT = 'STR' AND MONTH(MinDate) >= '07' and Month(MinDate) <= '09'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT RN, DP, DT, Min(ED) AS MinDate FROM ECount3 GROUP BY RN, DP, DT) as x WHERE DT = 'STR' AND MONTH(MinDate) >= '07' and Month(MinDate) <= '09'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT RN, DP, DT, Min(ED) AS MinDate FROM ECount4 GROUP BY RN, DP, DT) as x WHERE DT = 'STR' AND MONTH(MinDate) >= '07' and Month(MinDate) <= '09'
) as StrAFT
```

Simplify the case

```
-- This will return 1 row with 1
SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 1

-- This will return 2 rows with 1
SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1
```

As suggested by e_i_pi, you can remove the first `SELECT ()`, it done nothing in your query